# aiohttp: Serve single static file

Tags: http, python-asyncio, aiohttp

**How to serve a single static file (instead of an entire directory) using aiohttp?**

Static file serving seems to be baked into the routing system with [UrlDispatcher.add_static()](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.UrlDispatcher.add_static), but this only serves entire directories.

(I know that I eventually should use something like nginx to serve static files in a production environment.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently there is no built-in way of doing this; however, there are plans in motion to [add this feature](https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/issues/468).

Answer (score 40):

You can use [`aiohttp.web.FileResponse`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/latest/web_reference.html#fileresponse), initialised with the path to the file, e.g.

```py
from aiohttp import web

async def index(request):
    return web.FileResponse('./index.html')
```

Answer (score 8):

I wrote App, that handles uri on client (angular router).

To serve webapp i used slightly different factory:

```py
def index_factory(path,filename):
    async def static_view(request):
        # prefix not needed
        route = web.StaticRoute(None, '/', path)
        request.match_info['filename'] = filename
        return await route.handle(request)
    return static_view

# json-api
app.router.add_route({'POST','GET'}, '/api/{collection}', api_handler)
# other static
app.router.add_static('/static/', path='../static/', name='static')
# index, loaded for all application uls.
app.router.add_get('/{path:.*}', index_factory("../static/ht_docs/","index.html"))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
# server
local_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static")
app.router.add_static('/static', local_dir)

# HTML
<a href="/static/main.css">
```